# Getting updated date for all the endpoints through an API

Tags: api, openfda

I am trying to build a code that download all files from the provided end points. However, I do not want to download the files everytime and will only download the files if the data in the endpoints is changed/added. I assume that this is provided by the "last_updated" field in the JSON as shown in the API reference JSON snippet - https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/.
What is the URL that provides me similar JSON output?

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans. That helped. Glad to see active participation in the community.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5430)

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint for downloads is: https://api.fda.gov/download.json

I would log a bug on https://github.com/FDA/open.fda.gov letting them know that the above endpoint should be documented.

Answer (score 1):

Confusing indeed -- the site doesn't appear to provide a query URL to get the provided JSON output, as you noticed.

For now, it seems like your best bet might be paginating through AWS S3 directory listings available at http://download.open.fda.gov/ and looking at each `<Content>`'s `<Key>` and `<LastModified>` timestamp.